# Interweave XML segments in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing

I'm given two XML segments that are always paired, like:

```
<root>
<ZID>123</ZID>
<ZID>456</ZID>
<ZID>789</ZID>
</root>

<root>
<ZTYPE>A</ZID>
<ZTYPE>B</ZID>
<ZTYPE>C</ZID>
</root>
```

I need to put these into the table like:

```
ID   TYPE
____ _____
123  A
456  B
789  C
```

Ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: That's not even well-formed XML, so I'd start by fixing that.

Comment: Where is the "xml" coming from?

Comment: Another system. I have no control over what I have to start with.

Answer (score 0):

One option (with corrected XML)

```
Declare @XML1 xml = '<root><ZID>123</ZID><ZID>456</ZID><ZID>789</ZID></root>'
Declare @XML2 xml = '<root><ZTYPE>A</ZTYPE><ZTYPE>B</ZTYPE><ZTYPE>C</ZTYPE></root>'

Select A.ID
      ,B.Type
 From (
        Select RN=Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL))
              ,ID = f.n.value('(.)[1]','int') 
         From  @XML1.nodes('root') t(n)
         Cross Apply t.n.nodes('*') f(n)
      ) A
 Join (
        Select RN=Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL))
              ,Type = f.n.value('(.)[1]','varchar(max)') 
         From  @XML2.nodes('root') t(n)
         Cross Apply t.n.nodes('*') f(n)
       ) B
 On A.RN=B.RN
 Order By A.RN
```

Returns

```
ID    Type
123   A
456   B
789   C
```

Comment: I like this, and it gets me what I want. Is there any concern about the Order By (Select NULL) in the windowed function call? Will SQL Server guarantee the order that it extracts the values from the XML?

Comment: @SeanWilkinson Valid concern when reading an actual table, but not when reading a table variable or xml.  The row_number will be true.  I use an XML parser and it has never failed to keep the proper sequence.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer, but my rep is too low to show.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the XML to work.

```
Declare @Hndl1                      int;
Declare @Hndl2                      int;

Declare @Xml_Str1                   Nvarchar(Max) = '<root>'
                                                  + '  <Record>'
                                                  + '    <ZID>123</ZID>'
                                                  + '  </Record>'
                                                  + '  <Record>'
                                                  + '    <ZID>456</ZID>'
                                                  + '  </Record>'
                                                  + '  <Record>'
                                                  + '    <ZID>789</ZID>'
                                                  + '  </Record>'
                                                  + '</root>';

Declare @Xml_Str2                   Nvarchar(Max) = '<root>'
                                                  + '  <Record>'
                                                  + '    <ZTYPE>A</ZTYPE>'
                                                  + '  </Record>'
                                                  + '  <Record>'
                                                  + '    <ZTYPE>B</ZTYPE>'
                                                  + '  </Record>'
                                                  + '  <Record>'
                                                  + '    <ZTYPE>C</ZTYPE>'
                                                  + '  </Record>'
                                                  + '</root>';

Display_Result:
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @Hndl1 OUTPUT, @Xml_Str1;
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @Hndl2 OUTPUT, @Xml_Str2;

    SELECT A.ROW_NBR,
           A.ZID,
           B.ZTYPE
    FROM (SELECT Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) AS ROW_NBR,
                 ZID
          FROM OPENXML (@Hndl1, '/root/Record',1)
             WITH ( [ZID]         VARCHAR(10) 'ZID') ) A
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) AS ROW_NBR,
                       ZTYPE
                FROM OPENXML (@Hndl2, '/root/Record',1)
                 WITH ( ZTYPE         VARCHAR(10) 'ZTYPE') ) B ON(A.ROW_NBR = B.ROW_NBR);

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @Hndl1;
    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @Hndl2;
```

Returns:

```
ROW_NBR ZID ZTYPE
1       123 A
2       456 B
3       789 C
```